# Implementing numpy.mean in Expression using Calculate Field Tool in ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, field-calculator

I am using ArcGIS 10.4 ModelBuilder.
I developed a model that iterates through a bunch of feature datasets.  I need to add a field to each one of these features and apply one formula on it. My formula consists on dividing one column by its mean.
I have implemented a formula on the "expression" part of the "Calculate Field" tool.  As it is shown in the image:

[image]

The result of this is always 1. It seems that the mean is calculated per row and not for the whole column.  So it is dividing the value by itself giving 1 as a result.
[image]

I have also tried to define my own mean, but so far with out success

```
def my_mean(sample):
 return sum(sample) / len(sample)
```

How should I proceed?

Comment: You can't do that you need to pre-calculate the sum value you can't call it in an expression. If you are using modelbuilder then use summary stats tool to compute the value then you would need to use inline variable substitution. This type of analysis is much easier in python and there are examples on this forum.

Comment: Thank you for answer me, I have tried this option first, however, it is not as efficient as I would like it to be. It creates extra files that I would not need in the future, and it just makes my model more complicated :(

Comment: From Hornbydd suggestion, if you write the table to `in_memory`, it'll be both faster, and temporary, which may solve your complaint. But yes, it is a couple extra steps in the model.

Comment: Thank you @KHimba, I do not know how to do that. I also have troubles connecting the result of the Summary Statistic with  `"Calculate Field"` Tool. I have no idea of how to call the value resulting from the `summary statistics` to the `Expression` line from the `"Calculate Field"` Tool. The latter is connected to the feature datasets which has the field `JP_S_Norm` and the `JoinProb_S` (from which I want the mean) I connected the `Summary Statistic` Result with the `Calculate Field` as `"Model Parameter"`, However this result is not visible in the Calculate field. I do not how to proceed.

Comment: Think about what you are doing, the summary stats tool creates a TABLE but your expression needs a single value (the sum of the field). So sticking a table into an expression is meaningless. You need to extract out the sum value into a variable that can be used in the expression in the calculate field tool. Explore the [Get Field Value](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/modelbuilder/a-quick-tour-of-using-model-only-tools.htm) tool.

Comment: Also read the help file on `in_memory`, it is very easy to use and has all the benefits that @KHibma outlines.